# Python text RPG commands, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I have already defined Player in a class, but how come I can't get it to print "true" whenever I enter "help"? I don't get any errors, but it simply continues the While loop. Am I just not seeing something?

```
Commands = { #In-game commands
    'help': help,
    'exit': exit
    }

def charactercreation():
    print("Welcome to the wasteland. What is your name? ")
    Player.name = input(">> ")
    Player.hp = 30
    Player.curhp = 30
    Player.per = 7
    Player.dr = 1
    Player.agi = 5

def isValidCMD(cmd):
    if cmd in Commands:
        return True
    return False

def main(Player): #Main function
    Player.dead = False
    while(Player.dead == False):
        input(">> ")

        if input(isValidCMD):
            print("True")

charactercreation()
main(Player)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
    input(">> ")

    if input(isValidCMD):
        print("True")
```

you're *asking for more input.* Try:

```
    cmd = input(">> ")

    if isValidCMD(cmd):
        print("True")
```

instead.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding! Remember to accept the answer (green check mark) if this helped you.